# Ubuntu 14.04 - Virtual Surround Sound?

Tags: sound, 14.04, software-recommendation

When I used to use Windows, I would always install Razer Surround. It worked wonders and I found the software amazing.

Now that I've switched to Ubuntu, I've found nothing on Google that is seemingly a good alternative to the previously mentioned software.

Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for ALSA called **vdownmix** that converts audio output from 2 to 4 or 6 channels. It is included in the [ALSA library additional plugins](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libasound2-plugins) package, that you can install from the Software Centre.

Checkout out [this guide](http://www.rpgameplace.de/blog/index.php?/archives/25-Virtual-Surround-for-stereo-headphones-with-ALSA.html) for usage details.